# On the which council did Joseph of Arimathea sit?

Tags: gospel-of-john

> Mark 15:43
>
> Joseph of Arimathea, a prominent member of the Council, who was himself waiting for the kingdom of God, went boldly to Pilate and asked for Jesus' body.

Of which council was Joseph of Arimathea a member?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's commonly thought to be the (Great) [Sanhedrin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanhedrin), Luke certainly implies it to be the same Council that sat in judgment on Jesus:

> <sup>50</sup> Now there was a man named Joseph, a member of the Council, a good and upright man, <sup>51</sup> who had not consented to their decision and action. He came from the Judean town of Arimathea, and he himself was waiting for the kingdom of God. - [Luke 23:50-51 NIV](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke%2023%3A50-51&version=NIV)

He earlier describes it as "...**the council of the elders of the people, both the chief priests and the teachers of the law**..." ([Luke 22:66)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=luke%2022%3A66&version=NIV)